# How to prevent vertical scroll and trigger horizontal by one swipe gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, gesture

I am working on a iOS app recently.
I have a scroll view contains 3 view horizontally.
Frame as below

> View1:(0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight)
>
> View2:(ScreenWidth, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight)
>
> View3:(2 *ScreenWidth, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight)

In each view, there is a tableview.

The issue is when I try to scroll the tableview inside of view2, the tableview scrolls vertically, before it stop scroll, I can not scroll left or right by swipe gesture. The swipe only stop the tableview from scrolling, I need swipe again to see View 1 or View3.
My question is during the tableview is scrolling, how can I stop the table from scrolling and scroll to left or right view by one swipe gesture?
I checked the APP "Hotel Tonight" can work like what I want. But I don't know how to do that.
Any comment is welcome.

Comment: does your above code set values like this : view1 (x, y, width, height)?

Comment: Change the views frame and try. View1:(0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight) View2:(ScreenWidth, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight) View3:(2*ScreenWidth, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight)  and also take care of your scrollview contentSize

Answer (score 0):

Increase the UITableView content height.

Comment: sorry, i made mistake, the frame is wrong. I correct it